# Issue with mapcontrol in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am trying to develop an app using map control in wp 8.1. I placed  map control and added service token from bing maps portal. To get the current location of the map I placed the below code

```
map1.MapServiceToken = "AutVzTJ62c1kL9L5ni3TBhm5nr1wGSSxL04Zrsw6DTTUeoTT7VqS1Vup4vFmSYaL";

        Geolocator gl = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition gp = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geopoint myloc = gp.Coordinate.Point;
        MapIcon mi = new MapIcon();

        map1.MapElements.Add(mi);
```

1.When I try to run my application the map control didn't shows the current location.

2.When I place the service token in XAML code and deploy the code I cant see the map control.

3.When I remove service token from the XAML and code behind file it fetches the current location

Please  help me. I want to use this service token and get the current location from map control. How to get the nearby search term in map control(I think it is possible in silverlight applications using BingMapsTask but coming to WP 8.1 we use launchAsyncUri with the help of query)

```
string uri = @"bingmaps:?cp=" + pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude +"~" + pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude + "&lvl=25"+"&where=petrolbunks";
```

By implementing this it launches he map in our phone app. But I need to show this in map control. How to do this.